# Why Wordpress can't see file category.php?

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginning in wordpress and I have a problem - my wordpress ignores file category.php. The posts is divided by categories 'news' and 'announcements'. I have changed permalinks, but it is not fix the problem. This is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

On local server all is ok, but on host machine I have this problem. At the same time if I switch to another theme, I can see my posts whis was divided by categories, but in this case wordpress uses file archive.php. In my own theme when I click 'news' I get all posts in index.php page. And one more picularities - there are uses links like this 'mysite.com/contacts/' but when I use url 'mysite/category/news/' I get error 500 in logs.
Please can anybody help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error, it's  was just a pars error in file category.php)